# How do I stop values from assigning to second array?

Tags: c

Anybody have any idea why my second Array is gaining values form my first? The **keylist.txt** file is simply `2 14 74 8 36 4 11`...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int keylist[6], guess_list[6], game = 1;
    char file_name[30];

    FILE *ifp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        keylist[i] = 0;
        guess_list[i] = 0;
    }

    ifp = fopen("keylist.txt", "r");

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &keylist[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d, %d\n", keylist[i], guess_list[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please read the tags wikis. [tag:generic-programming] has nothing to do with your post.

Comment: you need to be more clear with your problem. Please [edit] your question to include the desired behavior and the observed behavior of the program.

Comment: for(int i=0; i<7; i++) -  what's wrong with that?

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 6, 7, 30.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, Then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: always check C library functions for error indications.  I.E.for both the calls to `fopen(()` and the calls to `fscanf()`

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
for(int i = 0; i<7; i++)
{
    keylist[i] = 0;
    guess_list[i] = 0;
}
```

the arrays `keylist[]` and `guess_list[]` only contain 6 entries however the loop is indexing `0,1,2,3,4,5,6`  I.E. 7 entries

So is accessing beyond the upper bounds of those arrays.  This results in undefined behavior and is the main source of the problem.

Suggest changing the `for()` statements to:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
```